# Executing Databricks Notebook in Azure Data Factory gives: Operation on target Notebook1 failed

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

I have created an Azure Databricks Cluster with Runtime version of "7.5 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)" on which I have created a Notebook (Python code).

I'm trying to execute this Notebook from a pipeline built on Azure Data Factory, but I get the following error:

```
Operation on target Notebook1 failed: Databricks execution failed with error state Terminated. For more details please check the run page url: https://PATH
```

As per the given path, the real error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

The problem here is that I have installed all the libraries, as shown bellow:

[image: libraries Installed]

And I can import them successfully on the notebook (as shown bellow), matter of fact the whole script can be executed succefully when launched directly from the notebook:

[image: libraries imported]

The probelm, is that I cannot execute the notebook from Azure Data Factory, the first error I get is that there is no module pyodbc!

Should I add a pip install pyodbc on my notebook (is it reliable) ? Or did I missed something ?

Thanks,

Comment: are you running this notebook on existing cluster?

Comment: Yes, a cluster that I have created with Runtime version of "7.5 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)"

Comment: Hi @DSEB, did you get any progresses? If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a cluster with the same environment, but the code works well.
[image]

Run the pyodbc code:
[image]

Then I run the notebook in Data Factory, it also works well.
[image]

If you add a `pip install pyodbc` on your notebook, it should works but maybe not recommended.
Please try restart the cluster or re-install the `pyodbc` library.

HTH.